# python and sql retrieving results from table

Tags: python, sql

I've created a sql db which contains the following:

```
Database: [URL_PARSED]
    File name: E:\URL Parser\URL_PARSED.db
    File size: 2048 bytes
    Page size: 1024
    Encoding: UTF-8
    Auto vacuum: 0
    Tables: 1
    Views: 0
------------------------------------------------------------
Table [PARSED_URL]
    Fields: 7
        [Time_Extracted]: TEXT
        [scheme]: TEXT
        [location]: TEXT
        [Url_path]: TEXT
        [object_parameters]: TEXT
        [query]: 
        [search]: TEXT
    Foreign Keys: 0
    Indexes: 0
    Triggers: 0
    Unique constraints: 0
    Check constraints: 0
------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am trying the retrieve google search results using the following code:

```
connect_to_db = sqlite3.connect('URL_PARSED.db')
cursor_for_db =connect_to_db.cursor()

cursor_for_db.execute("SELECT * FROM URL_PARSED WHERE search ="q=") :
                       results = cursor_for_db.fetchone()
                       print (results)
```

can someone please help me as this is not working.

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: yeah it says 
E:\URL Parser>extract.py
  File "E:\URL Parser\extract.py", line 13
    cursor_for_db.execute("SELECT * FROM URL_PARSED WHERE search ="q=") :
                                                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

E:\URL Parser>

Comment: @SteveBarrett: you can [edit] your question to add such details. Your Python syntax is invalid, as is your indentation. The `:` shouldn't be there, and it isn't clear what parameters you are trying to use to search on.

Comment: There's an extra quote in that line.

Comment: @cdonts: even without the quote the syntax is invalid.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I can't guess what he's trying to do with that `q=` and `:`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm trying to search from the table PARSED_URL any item that starts with q= and then print it to the screen. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find all rows where `search` *starts* with `q=` you need to use the [LIKE operator](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like):

```
cursor_for_db.execute("SELECT * FROM URL_PARSED WHERE search LIKE 'q=%'")
```

The `%` wildcard makes this a starts-with search; any text that matches the pattern `q=` followed by anything else will match.

This constructs a single valid SQL query as a Python string, so everything between the opening `"` and closing `"` is the SELECT statement.

If you need to make the query parameterised, use a SQL parameter placeholder and pass in a sequence of parameter values; here you have just one, but you do need to append the `%` wildcard as part of the parameter value:

```
query = 'q=%'
cursor_for_db.execute("SELECT * FROM URL_PARSED WHERE search LIKE ?", (query,))
```

The `query` value will then be correctly quoted for you.

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon after the execute should'nt be here. And the quotes aren't properly escaped, it should be:

```
cursor_for_db.execute("SELECT * FROM URL_PARSED WHERE search ='q='")
results = cursor_for_db.fetchone()
print (results)
```

EDIT, as the OP said he wants the items that begins with q=, the query should be

```
SELECT * FROM URL_PARSED WHERE SUBSTR(search, 1, 2) = 'q='
```

Comment: Provided that the OP is indeed searching for the textual value `q=`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you're looking for:

```
cursor_for_db.execute("SELECT * FROM URL_PARSED WHERE search ='q='")
results = cursor_for_db.fetchone()
print (results)
```

But you should better use:

```
cursor_for_db.execute("SELECT * FROM URL_PARSED WHERE search = ?", ("q=",))
```